# Trouble with Mouse Gesture software, can't resinstall

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, touchpad, uninstall

This is about a failed program install, that happens to be the ASUS mouse gesture program. I'll explain the complete issue;

1. New Windows 10 Install - freshly built laptop.
2. Mouse gesture software installed from updates but has not installed properly - so cannot customise gestures and simple thing like two finger scroll is missing.
3. Attempted to Uninstall, windows would not allow. Rebooted in safe mode but still windows would not uninstall the software.
4. Attempted to simply install the downloaded touchpad software but windows does not allow
5. Downloaded an Uninstaller program and it successfully uninstalled the program and registry entries
6. Upon trying to install the touchpad software, windows still blocks the install, with the attached message

[image: Windows error message]

What steps can i take to get this to install?

Answer (score -1):

did you install atk package first? without it touchpad software/driver won't work

https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Apps_for_Win10/ATKPackage/ATK_Package_V100061.zip

https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Apps_for_Win10/SmartGesture/SmartGesture_Win10_64_VER4024_DriverOnly.zip

Comment: The error message clearly indicates that it's not this issue that we're dealing with here.